# Drupal Views relationship

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-views-relationship

In Drupal I have 3 content types (A, B, C) see [link](https://docs0.google.com/drawings/edit?id=1RXmUphk2HBQyyjO-aNjEOxIRzmEHAu8WFrFNtXZeTrM&hl=en&authkey=CPqt--0I). A and C contain a node reference to B.

Now I have a view which queries fields from A from an argument. I want to also show fields from C trough the relationschip with B, so:

- A has a nodereference of ID:1
- B has a Node ID:1

  I want to show fields from C where nodereference of ID is also 1. How is this possible? I can't figure out the mapping.

Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can easily go from A to B via the Node Reference but since the link is from C to B you *cannot* get the link to C -- this is the current problem.

In short, you can solve the problem by using the module Node Referrer (see http://drupal.org/node/431308 for what it does). Essentially it creates a *read only* field that tells you all the nodes pointing from C to B (i.e. a sort of reverse node reference is created for each node reference).

So lets say we have the following Node Reference fields

1. In content type A we have the node
   reference field called `a_to_b_link`
2. In content type C we have the node reference field called
   `c_to_b_link`
3. In content type B we have the Node Referrer field that tracks all
   the links in the Node Reference
   `c_to_b_link`

Creating the corresponding view is a little bit more involved.

1. First add a filter for `Node: Type =
   A`
2. Add a relationship `a_to_b_link`. Make sure the you tick the checkbox
   `Require this relationship`
3. Add another relationship from the Node group called `Node:
   Referrers`. Also make sure in the settings for the relationship you should
   choose the `a_to_b_link` in the `Relationship` drop down. In other words you are making a relationship that uses a pre-existing relationship (similar in concept to a *pointer to a pointer* in C++) Make sure the you tick the checkbox `Require this relationship`. This relationship by default is named `Referencing Nodes` by Drupal.
4. Now add whatever fields you want from content type A as you would do
   normally in the view.
5. When you want to add fields from content type C make sure you select
   the relationship `Referencing Nodes`

Comment: @Nealv: Instead of Node Referrer (that i've used) you can also look at http://drupal.org/project/reverse_node_reference (it requires MySQL 5.1). See http://drupal.org/node/798786 for differences with Node Referrer. Essentially the main advantage is that you would not need to create a fresh field in content type B. You will just get a reverse node reference in views relationships. It might be a little bit more "elegant" in that respect. But both methods will work.